# Is this function a metric? Proof or counterexample.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a finite set with cardinality $n$. Consider the two partitions $A,B$ of $X$. Suppose $A(x)$ is the cell containing $x$ in $A$, and likewise $B(x)$ is the corresponding cell in $B$. For each $x\in X$ define

$S(x):=A(x)\Delta B(x),\quad \text{and}\quad S=\{S(x)\neq\emptyset:x\in X\}$

Now consider $d(A,B):=\sum_{S(x)\in S}\frac{r}{\dbinom{n}{s}}$ where $s$ is the cardinality of $S(x)$ and $r$ is the total number of cells in $S$ with cardinality $s$.

To make things clear, consider $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, $A=\{\{x_1,x_3\},\{x_2 \}\}$ $B=\{\{x_1\},\{x_2\},\{x_3\}\}$. Then $S=\{\{x_2\},\{x_1\}\}$. Note that $A(x_2)\Delta B(x_2)=\emptyset$ and it is not included in $S$ by definition. Then $d(A,B)=\frac{2}{\dbinom{3}{1}}=\frac{2}{3}$.

Given those above, my question is that is this function a metric? I tried to prove it but I haven't been able to prove triangle inequality. Also I couldn't find a counterexample. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there some sort of intuition to go with that series of definitions?

Comment: Well my understanding is it takes a symmetric difference so it measures how far apart each cells that contain given element. These symmetric differences create subsets of the original set $X$. The function count these subsets with the same cardinality and weights them according to probability of obtaining them. That is what I understand from it.

Comment: Yes, but what made you combine that particular sequence of operations and consider that it might be a metric? What's the motivation for the definition?